# How to find index of First non-zero element in a list (Language - Ocaml)

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I am trying to find the index of first non zero number in a array. To explain it further here is what expected,

*Consider a Array* - `[0;0;1;2;0;4;5;6]`

Expected result will be index of number `1` which should *return result index should be* `2nd`.

It will be great, if the answer avoid use of sequence operator and loops.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @didierc I tried the one below and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `let`, sequence op `;`, `for` and `while` within the vanilla OCaml, I can write:

```
class c = object (self)
  method f i = function
    | x::_ when x <> 0 -> i
    | _::xs -> self#f (i+1) xs
    | [] -> failwith "Got the answer from StackOverflow"
end
;;

(new c)#f 0 [0;0;1;2;0;4;5;6];;
```

Comment: Use of let is allowed only for naming rec and non- recursive function... and i need program without classes in ocaml